# Error- Cannot read property 'Function' of undefined (secureAnonymousFramework)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, azure, linkedin-api, linker-errors

I'm trying to use Member Profile Plugin on my website using code from generator:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/MY-PROFILE" data-format="inline" data-related="false"></script>
```

It looks nice on the generator preview, but when I insert these lines on my website, I'm getting following error:

```
secureAnonymousFramework?v=1.0.78-1429&:1031 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Function' of undefined
at secureAnonymousFramework?v=1.0.78-1429&:1031
at secureAnonymousFramework?v=1.0.78-1429&:3181
```

My website is built with ASP.NET MVC technology hosted on Azure.

What's wrong with that plugin? How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong with that plugin? How to fix this error?

I test it on my side with a new asp.net mvc project, it works correctly on my side. It seems that it is not related to your supplied code and azure platform. You also could test it with a new project.

**The following is my test steps:**

1.Get code with [Member Profile Plugin Generator](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile)

[image]

2.Create an Asp.net MVC project,copy and paste the code into Index.cshtml file.

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxx" data-format="inline" data-related="false">
</script>
```

3.Publish the project to Azure site and check the result.

[image]